# When does a closure take ownership of its environment without the move keyword?

Tags: rust

```
use std::thread;

fn test2() {
    let x = "abc".to_string();
    thread::spawn(|| {
        foo2(x);
    });
}

fn foo2(x: String) {}

fn test1() {
    let x = 1;
    thread::spawn(|| { 
        foo1(x); 
    });
}

fn foo1(x: i32) {}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=93fb93d03a073d9cf3bb56e85f58fd87&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
  --> <anon>:12:19
   |
12 |     thread::spawn(|| { foo1(x); });
   |                   ^^        - `x` is borrowed here
   |                   |
   |                   may outlive borrowed value `x`
   |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `x` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
   |     thread::spawn(move || { foo1(x); });
```

Why does the closure in `test1` not take ownership of `x`, which is specified by the signature (`x: i32`) of `foo1`? (I know I can add `move` to make it work.) I guess it is due to that `x` is copyable, but if it is copied into the closure then why do I still have the lifetime problem?

However `test2` works.

Comment: This looks like a misconception of what closures do by default. Without `move`, the closure will always borrow the necessary external resources. It doesn't even matter if they implement `Copy`.

Comment: @Shepmaster that format button looks neat. I have always overlooked it.

Comment: Alright; I've changed it back to your original code, updated the playground link to match the code you wanted, and included the error. The error is the **important thing that was missing**, which is why I started down this path. I apologize for changing the meaning of your code, but please also take care to *include error messages* when asking about them!

Comment: @E_net4 I know by default it tries to borrow. But I think sometimes it does take ownership like in case `test2`

Comment: @Shepmaster In my original question, I commented inline briefly about the error (perhaps it easily gets neglected). I think next time I would post the whole error message in a new block like you did.

Comment: @colinfang that would be ideal. When we are faced with a problem or error message we don't understand, that is not the best time to try to summarize it, as we, by definition, don't know enough to do so reliably ^_^. Posting the complete error message makes sure that everyone is able to reproduce the exact same issue you are seeing and reduces the potential for misplaced answers. The full text also has much more detail compared to the summarized version, which can be useful for us to help understand and explain the original problem.

Comment: @E_net4, The Book has [an example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#closures-and-their-environment) where non-move closure takes ownership of a variable: `let nums = vec![1, 2, 3]; let takes_nums = || nums;`

Comment: Indeed, I stand corrected. Only realised that upon a second look at the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it doesn't *have* to take ownership.  Moving is more destructive than simply borrowing, so if the compiler thinks it can get away with not moving a captured value, it won't.  It moves the `String` because it has no other option.  It borrows the `i32` because it's `Copy`.

> But it *can't* get away with not borrowing it!

Aah, but the compiler *doesn't know that* until *after* it's decided if it's borrowing or moving a captured value.  The heuristic it uses is just that: not always correct.

> Couldn't it just work it out properly?

Probably, but no one's taught it how.

Comment: Why would it borrow if the value is `Copy`? I had thought that the compiler would more likely to move because of `Copy`

Comment: @colinfang: `Copy` means it can make a copy of the value whenever it pleases.  So it can just borrow it and copy when (and *if*) it needs a value.  With a non-`Copy` type, it *can't* make a copy to pass to `foo2`, so it *has* to move it.  Even if a type is `Copy`, it could still be huge.

Comment: I see, so in this case, it tries to borrow at the closure creation and to make a copy when `foo1` is called.

Comment: I find this discrepancy jarring, actually. I guess it doesn't have much choice (with no way to opt-out of move, it has to only be used when mandatory), but it is jarring nonetheless.